# SAPUI5 reuse Views and make new instance

Tags: model-view-controller, view, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am new in SAP and trying to develop a SAPUI5 application, but faced some problems when reusing views/partial views. I want to have a partial view and pass custom data in a specefic format (data changes but model is same), and reuse these partial view many times in one page, every time passing different data. Somehow like Tiles, but very cuszomized. 
what do you suggest me to use? 
I have tryied to make new instance of a regular view but faced this error:

> GET https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/view/List.view.xml 404
>   (Not Found)

this is my code to make new instance:

```
var firstListView=sap.ui.xmlview("firstViw", "view.List");
```

thanks for your help

Update: 
this is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />

    <script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.ushell"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
            "sap.ui.appName": "./"
        }'>
    </script>
    <script src="../libs/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="css/theme/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>

        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                appWidthLimited:false,
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    name: "sap.ui.appName"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the folder structered:

[image]

Comment: About the error: What is your namespace defined at `resourceRoots` in index.html? And how is your project folder structured? Would be nice if you could update the question accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have upated the question. @boghyon

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at chapter “Reusing UI Parts: Fragments” of the UI5 SDK.
Here is an excerpt. Please have a look whether this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you suggest to use fragments in this case?

Comment: The [Walkthrough](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee) (steps 15-17) explains this quite good by instantiating a dialogue as a fragment.